# How to determine the rules of a fuzzy system with 3 inputs and 1 output?

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I am creating a fuzzy system in matlab as part of my final year computer science work for fuzzy logic.
I have created my 3 inputs variable so
Wind speed:
Low
Average 
High

Visibility:
Low
Medium 
Clear

Wind direction:
Safe1 
Danger1
Safe2
Danger2
Safe3

Output
Safe to takeoff
Take of with caution 
Take of not allowed

What I am asking is if I made a rule say
If Visibility is Low AND Windows speed is Low AND wind direction is safe 2 THEN .............

How would I determine the output with the 3 input variables as I know it is simple with 2 input variables as a table can be created?

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of fuzzy systems is that you do heuristics. If you have an equation, or a maths way of knowing that then its not a fuzzy system anymore

Comment: Thanks for that cleared it  up nicely.